# A cube has 8 vertices (±1, ±1, ±1). We draw vectors from the center (0, 0, 0) to three top vertices. What is the volume of the parallelepiped formed?

Tags: vectors, 3d

for clarification: the top vertices are those with z = 1.

I figured I could simply use $P = (1,1,1) Q = (-1,1,1) R = (1,-1,1) S = (-1,-1,1)$

Which would give $ PQ = <-2,0,0> PR = <0,-2,0> PS = <-2,-2,0> $

And then use the formula for the volume of a parellelepiped $PQ . (PR X PS)$
however this gave me a result of $0$.
I do not think I made a mistake in calculating, so I'm assuming I am not using the correct method.

Any help would be greatly appreciated!
thank you.

Comment: Isn't the object a triangular pyramid? There are only four vertices (origin, and three vertices of cube).

Comment: the center of the cube is at $(0,0,0)$ so there are four vertices in the positive z direction.

Comment: Oh I see now, four points can be completed to form a parallelepiped and the volume does not matter how you complete it (analogous to how three points in a plane can be completed to form a parallelogram whose volume does not depend on how you complete it).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Choose 3 of $P,Q,R, S$ as above.  It doesn't matter which 3.

The volume of the parallelepiped, formed with theses points and the origin equals the absolute value of determinant of the matrix formed from those points.

$\left| \begin{array}{} 1&1&1\\-1&1&1\\1&-1&1 \end{array}\right| = 4$

Comment: Is there a way to find this using the equation for the volume of a parallelepiped?

Comment: Alright your answer clued me in! thank you! guess I got down-voted for not realizing to use (0,0,0) as one of the points, which is pretty obvious :(